# how to add and edit 2 views in one view controller in xcode 4.2 from Interface Builder in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I am Abbas,I am new to iPhone Development,

Till tomorrow i am using xcode 3.2 sdk and build in interface builder,

I have updated my xcode to 4.2,

If i am adding another view to existing view controller by assigning IBOutlet View *view1,

and edit my new view from Interface Builder, it does not able to edit.

and also my previous Interface builder is not showing.

What i can do, Give me any suggestion,

Please Help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From xcode4, interface builder is integrated into xcode, it isn't a single UI any more.

You can easily edit it through just single click the .xib file. Maybe there is some wrong operation. I recommend you to close xcode3.2 and the project , then reopen the project only in xcode 4.2 .

Comment: Yes you are right in my xcode 4.2 on single click on xib it is open,I know that and also tried this, but problem is that, I created new project name it "test" subclass of UIViewController, i edit view of Uiviewcontroller ,add it a label, changed text to "Hello". I want to add another view for that i created IBOutlet UIView *view1, and open xib file add another view, but when i am clicking on that it does not open, Please Help.

Comment: I'am not very clear about your problem. You mean that you add another UIView in the existed xib file? When you are clicking the existed xib file, the file is not open?

Comment: No not that, Xib file is opening but UIView not opening.

Comment: @AbbasMulani You say the xib file is opening but UIView not opening. So the UIView is another file? I guess not. Is the UIView in the same xib file?

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your response, i have deleted all xcode related files from Developers,and Install Xcode 3.2, my problem is solved.Thank you very much because you helped me.Can you give your facebook id I want to add you as a Friend. Thanks again.The Problem is in Interface Builder.I have 2 interface builder and it was malfunctioning. Thanks alot Sir.

Comment: @AbbasMulani I'm happy to hear that you solve the problem. I am in China and the facebook & twitter is blocked by the damn government. We have our own "facebook" website named renren.com, but it only has chinese version, you won't like it.

Comment: ok no problem you can also give me gmail id, i will invite you to chat, you have to accept my chat request, and i truly speaking that i have no friend out of India.So give your gmail id please.or you can take my gmail id and invite me to chat.My gmail id is:(abbas.mulani@gmail.com) thanks.